# how to handle custom token with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I have a node express APP. 
I know we can use 'jsonwebtoken' and 'express-jwt'. to. verify and generate token. But my question is what if my token is not generated by jsonwebtoken.  how can I apply token protect my API?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code of how you are generating the token.

Comment: my token gernerated by third party API,  which is means only verifiable by that API

Comment: Still, the below answer can work for you but you don't need steps 1 & 2.
In step 4, inside the try-catch, you can make a call to the 3rd party API  and work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the approach would be.

1. Create a function to generate the custom token as you like.

```
const sign = (data, secret) => {
  //your logic goes here
}
```

2. Create a function that verifies the token.

```
const verify = (token, secret) => {
   // returns error or decoded data
}
```

3. Call it whenever you want to create a token say after login success

```
const login = (req, res) => {
  // login code goes here say its success
  const token = sign({id: _id}, process.env.SECRET_KEY)
  res.json({token: token})
}
```

4. Validate the token received in the protected route. Create a middleware function for the same.

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {

  //token from the request header
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'] // -> or key of your choice
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401) // if there isn't any token

  try{
      const data = verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY) => {
      if (err) return res.status(403)
      req.user_id = data.id // this one will let you read data in the calling service function
      next() // pass the execution off to whatever request the client intended
    }
  } catch (err) {
     res.send(err)
  }
}
```

5. Reading data from token

```
const getUserInfo = (req, res) => {
    const id = req['user_id'];
    // now you can get the user data using this id that we used while signing the token.
}
```

Now as I come to know that the token is provided by 3rd Party and it can be verified by them only.

So in this case,

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {

  //token from the request header
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'] // -> or key of your choice
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401) // if there isn't any token

  try{
      // make the verify call to the 3rd party api by sending the token 
      // received in the request
      const data = ApiCall();

      /* set that data into the header, if you may want to use it later or 
       * do whatever you want to do.
       */
      req.resp_data = data;
      next(); // sent control to next function.

  } catch (err) {
     res.send(err)
  }
}
```

Hope this helped.